# I wanna send strings to serial port in c# for unity, but get little stuck

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, serial-port

Well im ring to send these 50+ strings to make a game that dispenses a prize, so I using Unity to develop games, so my main idea is to use this code as a base to the string sending code the code in my idea its almost ready I think I have some problems with the strongly typed C#. Im really new to C#, im more in Java. So I accept all kind of advice

Thanks

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System;
 

public class VendComms : MonoBehaviour {
 
    // Action Constants
    const string CAB1   = "02 06 00 85 00 01 8e";
    const string CAB2   = "02 06 00 85 00 02 8f";
    const string CAB3   = "02 06 00 85 00 03 90";
    const string CAB4   = "02 06 00 85 00 04 91";
    const string CAB5   = "02 06 00 85 00 05 92";
    const string CAB6   = "02 06 00 85 00 06 93";
    const string CAB11  = "02 06 00 85 00 0b 98";
    const string CAB12  = "02 06 00 85 00 0c 99";
    const string CAB13  = "02 06 00 85 00 0d 9a";
    const string CAB14  = "02 06 00 85 00 0e 9b";
    const string CAB15  = "02 06 00 85 00 0f 9c";
    const string CAB16  = "02 06 00 85 00 10 9d";
    const string CAB17  = "02 06 00 85 00 11 9e";
    const string CAB18  = "02 06 00 85 00 12 9f";
    const string CAB19  = "02 06 00 85 00 13 a0";
    const string CAB21  = "02 06 00 85 00 15 a2";
    const string CAB22  = "02 06 00 85 00 16 a3";
    const string CAB23  = "02 06 00 85 00 17 a4";
    const string CAB24  = "02 06 00 85 00 18 a5";
    const string CAB25  = "02 06 00 85 00 19 a6";
    const string CAB26  = "02 06 00 85 00 1a a7";
    const string CAB27  = "02 06 00 85 00 1b a8";
    const string CAB28  = "02 06 00 85 00 1c a9";
    const string CAB29  = "02 06 00 85 00 1d aa";
    const string CAB31  = "02 06 00 85 00 1f ac";
    const string CAB32  = "02 06 00 85 00 20 ad";
    const string CAB33  = "02 06 00 85 00 21 ae";
    const string CAB34  = "02 06 00 85 00 22 af";
    const string CAB35  = "02 06 00 85 00 23 b0";
    const string CAB36  = "02 06 00 85 00 24 b1";
    const string CAB37  = "02 06 00 85 00 25 b2";
    const string CAB38  = "02 06 00 85 00 26 b3";
    const string CAB39  = "02 06 00 85 00 27 b4";
    const string CAB41  = "02 06 00 85 00 29 b6";
    const string CAB42  = "02 06 00 85 00 2a b7";
    const string CAB43  = "02 06 00 85 00 2b b8";
    const string CAB44  = "02 06 00 85 00 2c b9";
    const string CAB45  = "02 06 00 85 00 2d ba";
    const string CAB46  = "02 06 00 85 00 2e bb";
    const string CAB47  = "02 06 00 85 00 2f bc";
    const string CAB48  = "02 06 00 85 00 30 bd";
    const string CAB49  = "02 06 00 85 00 31 be";
    const string CAB51  = "02 06 00 85 00 33 c0";
    const string CAB52  = "02 06 00 85 00 34 c1";
    const string CAB53  = "02 06 00 85 00 35 c2";
    const string CAB54  = "02 06 00 85 00 36 c3";
    const string CAB55  = "02 06 00 85 00 37 c4";
    const string CAB56  = "02 06 00 85 00 38 c5";
    const string CAB57  = "02 06 00 85 00 39 c6";
    const string CAB58  = "02 06 00 85 00 3a c7";
    const string CAB59  = "02 06 00 85 00 3b c8";
    
    const string CAB00  = "02 06 00 85 00 00 00";
 
    // Port for connecting to Vending;
    System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp;
 
    //string arrays for sending and recieving bit strings
    string[] send, receive;
 
    // string to send when ready
    string to_be_sent_;
 
    // bools to continue loops in threads
    bool continueReading_;
    bool continueWriting_;
 
    //Thread readThread;
 
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
 
        sp = new SerialPort();
 
        sp.PortName = "usbserial-14620";
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
 
        send = new string[1];
        receive = new string[1];
        
        this.to_be_sent_ = CAB00;
        //sp.DataReceived += get_serial_data;
 
        try
        {
            sp.Open();
            Debug.Log("Puerto Abierto");
 
            //// Setup the thread to poll the port on
            Thread readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(get_serial));
            this.continueReading_ = true;
            readThread.Start();
 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error abriendo el Puerto: " + e.Message);
        }
 
    }
 
    string get_command(string command)
    {
        if (command == CAB1)
            return "Gabinete 1";
        else if (command == CAB2)
            return "Gabinete 2";
        else if (command == CAB3)
            return "Gabinete 3";
        else if (command == CAB4)
            return "Gabinete 4";
        else if (command == CAB5)
            return "Gabinete 5";
        else if (command == CAB6)
            return "Gabinete 6";
        else
            return "Comando Desconocido..";
    }
 
    void get_serial()
    {
        while (continueReading_)
        {
            //sp.Read(receive, 0, 1);
            // RECEIVING STRINGS
            receive[0] = (string)sp.ReadByte();
            Thread.Sleep(20);
 
            sp.DiscardInBuffer();
            UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.print("Recibiendo:    " + get_command(receive[0]));
 
        }
 
    }
 
    void OnDisable()
    {
        sp.Close();
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
 
        // Set the signal to be sent
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            this.to_be_sent_ = CAB1;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            this.to_be_sent_ = CAB2;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            this.to_be_sent_ = CAB3;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            this.to_be_sent_ = CAB4;
        }
 
        // Send the signal
        if (this.to_be_sent_ != CAB00)
        {
            //> set the string to be sent
            send[0] = (string)this.to_be_sent_;
 
            // Write to the lamp
            sp.WriteLine(send, 0, 1 );
 
            sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
            print("Enviado:       " + get_command(send[0]));
 
            this.to_be_sent_ = (string)CAB00;
        }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: The port name should be like `"COM1"` or `"\\.\COM1"`. Assuming this is Windows.

Comment: Im working currently on Mac, also im using a TTL to RS232 for communication with the machine

Answer (score 0):

`receive[0] = (string)sp.ReadByte();` does that compile? You can't cast a `byte` to a `string`. It looks like you want to build up a message of bytes. You can do this by filling in the array one byte at a a time as you read from the port. When you get a full message, convert to string an process.

```
void get_serial()
{
    byte [] receive = new byte[7];
    int index = 0;
    while (continueReading_)
    {
        // Read a byte and add to the array
        byte data = sp.ReadByte();
        if (data == 2) {
            index = 0;  // Start of msg
        }
        receive[index++] = data;

        // Check for full msg
        if (index == 7) {
            if (receive[0] == 2) {
               // Convert byte array to string
               string formattedBytes = String.Concat(receive.Select(i => string.Format("{0:x2} ", i))).Trim();
               var cmd = get_command(formattedBytes);
               UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.print("Recibiendo: " + cmd);
            }
            index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

However, instead of using a thread I suggest using the built in `SerialPort` callback functionality. It looks like you tried that but commented it out.

```
// sp.DataReceived += get_serial_data;
```

Uncomment that, lose the `Thread` and make some minor modifications to `get_serial`.

```
byte [] receive = new byte[7];
int index = 0;
void get_serial_data()
{
    while (SerialPort.BytesToRead != 0)
    {
        byte data = sp.ReadByte();
        .... the rest is the same ....
    }
}
```